# JQuery created form created is not submitting

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I'm quite new to Jquery coding and I'm having an issue that I cannot figure out why:

I have a table containing buttons that when clicked will allow the user to edit the values of that same row:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>data1</td>  
    <td>data2</td>  
    <td>data3</td>  
    <td><input type="button" class="alter" value="Alter"></td>
  </tr>
  ...
  <tr>
    <!-- Same structure as row above -->
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

When I click the button, I want that same table row to be changed to:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <td><input type="hidden" name="editData1" value="data1">data1</td>  
      <td><input type="number" name="editData2" value="data2"></td>  
      <td><input type="number" name="editData3" value="data3"></td>  
      <td><input type="submit" name="editData" value="Edit"></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
  ...
  <tr>
    <!-- Remain unchanged -->
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I use Jquery to do that, as you can see:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.alter').click(function(){

    var data1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    var data2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    var data3 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

    $(this).closest('tr').html('<form action="" method="post"><td><input type="hidden" name="editData1" value="'+data1+'">'+data1+'</td><td><input type="number" name="editData2" value="'+data2+'"></td><td><input type="number" name="editData3" value="'+data3+'"></td><td><input type="submit" name="editData" value="Edit"></td></form>');


  }); 
});
```

The problem is:

When I click in the Alter button, the Jquery automatically does all the structural changes in the table, inserting the form, inputs and submit buttons, but when I try to click on the Edit button to submit the form, nothing happens.

I even copied the html that the Jquery is inserting between the tr tags to another page and tested if the form was submitting, and it was everything ok!

Can anyone help me figure out why is this happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only programmed the html-level changes when user starts editing, but you did not program what happens when the user finishes editing. `$('input[name="editData"]').click(function(){ RESTORE TABLE, SAVE CHANGES,  ETC  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's invalid HTML to have a `<form>` tag within a `<tr>` tag that then has `<td>` tags in it. When you generate these elements, the browser is being smart and automatically closing the form before the first td, so the submit button isn't within the form.

Try this instead:

```
$(this).closest('tr').html('<td><form action="" method="post"><span><input type="hidden" name="editData1" value="'+data1+'">'+data1+'</span><span><input type="number" name="editData2" value="'+data2+'"></span><span><input type="number" name="editData3" value="'+data3+'"></span><span><input type="submit" name="editData" value="Edit"></span></form></td>')
```

And you may want to have some CSS like this:

```
tr form span {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Wampastompa, now the form worked like a charm! The only issue is that I cannot make the <span> tags look like table cells.  
The CSS that you provided does not make any changes. It is targeting the right elements, but does not make the vertical splits like the td tags. What shoud I do?